# how to show adbkit install progress

Tags: installation, adb, progress

Code may like this:

```
        client.install(device_id, xxx.apk)
            .then(function (transfer) {
                transfer.on('progress', function (stats) {
                    console.log('[%s] Pushed %d bytes so far',
                                device_id, stats.bytesTransferred);
                })
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("error");
            })
```

How can I get install progress?